# How to put a timer between 2 bot messages / commands

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've made a discord bot, here the code

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
   console.log("I am ready!");
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
if (message.content.startsWith("!kevin")) {
  message.channel.send("i'm kevin");
}
if (message.content.startsWith("!thomas")) {
  message.channel.send("random text blabla");
}
```

Basically, when I type !something,  my bot answer in the chat by the proper line,  my current issue is my discord is kinda big nowadays, and I would like to restrict the bot to only  X messages per minutes, but I can't find an easy function to do that

my question :

Is it possible to get a timer between 2 messages to send by the bot, because without that my bot is just spamming answer to each users typing `!somethingsomething`, I would like my bot to as soon as someone type `!something`, the bot lock itself of replying to any other `!something` for X amount of time

Example,

User 1 : !thomas

User 2 : !thomas

User 3 : !thomas

But the bot only reply to one of them and put a timer to himself before being able to send a new `!message` reply

So basically, is it any way to make the bot reply to X amounts of !cmd  each minutes, or to limits the cooldown between 2 messages the bot send

here my script : https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b8W5.jpg   ( i know its terrible especially since it have over 9000 differents !cmd , but i converted quickly a old MIRC script and im terrible at javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Cooldown for the users and/or bot

So I found out from your comments that you want the bot to only run a command only every "X" amount of time. I don't recommend this, I recommend just preventing USERS from registering a cmd every "X" amount of time. I've included both in this example.

```js
let lastCmdSentTime = {};
let waitTimeForUser =  60000 * 5; //Users can only run a command once every 5 minutes
let botLastSent = false;
let timeBetweenEachCmd = 60000; //Bot will only respond once a minute.

client.on("message", (message) => {
   if(botLastSent !== false ? message.createdTimestamp - botLastSent < timeBetweenEachCmd : false) return; //don't let the bot run a cmd every [timeBetweenEachCmd]
   let userLastSent = lastCmdSentTime[message.author.id] || false;
   if(userLastSent !== false ? message.createdTimestamp - userLastSent < waitTimeForUser : false) return; //don't let the user run a cmd every [waitTimeForUser]
   lastCmdSentTime[message.author.id] = message.createdTimestamp;
   botLastSent = message.createdTimestamp;


   //RUN COMMANDS

});
```

Comment: iv try to use your script but i think discord.js dont like "let" or cause some kind of bug, iv try to copy ur code to try it on my code which is basicaly 
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("I am ready!");
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
if (message.content.startsWith("!kevin")) {
message.channel.send("www.google.com");
}

But i cant make it work i cant even start the node, i just got syntaxerror and missing argument list i guess let is not reconize

Comment: ok iv edited the  last  line by " } "   to  });  and the node started, but iv try to type !anycommand multiple times and the timer doesnt work, i can type 20 x  any !cmd and the bot instantly reply for each of the 20 !cmd  seems like the 5 minutes timer doesnt work

Comment: had some typos, should be fixed.

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks alot @frustrated programmer

Answer (score 0):

## Cooldown for commands

Simply store the date the command was ran, then check if a certain amount has passed since the date was set.
**Example:**
*Edited to support multiple commands*

```js
let date = false;
let commandsTimers = {
    "!kevin":{
       waitTime: 5 * 60000, // 5 minutes wait for this particular command.
       lastUsed: false,
    }
}
let defaultWaitTime = 60000 * 2; //User needs to wait 2 minutes for each command unless specified
client.on("message", (message) => {
    let msgSentDate = Date.now();
    let commandWaitTimer = commandsTimers[message.content.split(" ")[0]] || {waitTime:defaultWaitTime, lastUsed:false}; 
    if((commandWaitTimer.lastUsed !== false ? msgSentDate - commandWaitTimer.lastUsed < commandWaitTimer.waitTime : false)){
        console.log('User needs to wait: ' + (commandWaitTimer.waitTime - (msgSentDate - commandWaitTimer .lastUsed)) / 1000 + ' seconds');
        return
    }
    commandsTimers[message.content.split(" ")[0]].lastUsed = msgSentDate;

    if (message.content.startsWith("!thomas")) {        
        message.channel.send("random text blabla");
    }
    if (message.content.startsWith("!kevin")) {        
        message.channel.send("Kevin!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, and thanks you for your message, i like the way u do that but the issue is i got like over 9000 !commands,, so i would like/need the same kind but in a general manner, like a global array/function basicaly

Comment: are you doing EACH command like `if(message.content.startsWith(command))`? or do you store each cmd in a module? Like would the command running have access to what command is being ran? Like if you stored each command in a object, you could pass in the command's name as you `.run` the command.

Comment: i wanted to edit my message but 5 mnt to edit my post, im a beginer and i basicaly converted an old mIRC script, so i have like 9000+ 

 " if (message.content.startsWith("!thomas")) {
message.channel.send("random text blabla");
} "

I need a way to avoid 20 users of typings !cmd and then my bot to spam 20 lines of reply,  do you know a way to just do a global timer, like the bot can only reply to !something  once every X seconds or minutes,

basicaly it look like that : https://i.imgur.com/Q7w98Rm.jpg

Comment: Copy-pasting code around the place is not the way to write code. That's the reason we write code in the first place, so we don't have to copy-paste chunks, but programatically define behaviors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @RokoC.Buljan , i never said it was quality code, it was a convertion of an old Mirc script, especially because i'm not good at all at javascript, if you know a proper way or guide , or explaination to help me progress this way or to improve it i would be more than happy,  if your message was just to point  the fact than my " script " is totaly ass, dont worry i already know it, i just want to learn / try to make it less ass :)

Comment: @Ocato I was talking about the 9*2 chunks of code provided here :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan just realized a solution to cut down the code, ty for making me think about the problem. But I've updated this solution to have less code.

Comment: @Frustratedprogrammer ok iv edited the last line by " } " to }); and the node started, but iv try to type !anycommand multiple times and the timer doesnt work, i can type 20 x any !cmd and the bot instantly reply for each of the 20 !cmd seems like the 5 minutes timer doesnt work